# Get current model name and file path in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to open the current model or submodel in an external program.
Currently, I am adding a command to all models by hand. For example:

```
system("mytool --path \"C:\\MyModel.mo\" --model \"MyModel.SubModel\"");
```

Is there a function that returns the current model's path and name?

**Edit:**
`classDirectory()` and `getWorkingDirectory()` return only a directory.
The Model Management Library [(PDF Documentation)](http://marketing.intrinsys.co.uk/V6_2013x_PDir/pdf/catia_dbm_model_management_library.pdf) seems to be able to analyze the AST of a model. This looks like it could solve my problem, but it seems like overkill and I don't have a license.

I had hoped to find an easy way to do this. For example, in Matlab/Simulink I can just use `which(bdroot)` and `getfullname(gcb)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-standard builtin function called classDirectory() which will return the directory of the class is called from. There might be also some other way using ModelManagement library or how is called.